# pandas replacing the contents of a column based on the conditions another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data-frame. one column has string variables and the other column has 1's and 0's. Depending on a percentile threshold of 1's occurring against each values of the string column i want to replace the value with either 1 or 0.

the two columns of `'train_data'` dataframe are "Issue" and "Customer disputed?"

Issue

Billing statement

Making/receiving payments, sending money

Incorrect information on credit report

Billing statement

Transaction issue

Loan modification,collection,foreclosure

Loan servicing, payments, escrow account

Loan modification,collection,foreclosure

Credit card protection / Debt protection

Consumer disputed?
No
No
No
No
No
No
No
Yes
No

My codes:

```
b = pd.crosstab(train_data['Issue'], train_data['Consumer disputed?']).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=1)

b['Issue_max'] = np.where(b[1]>=0.2, 1, 0)

train_data = train_data.merge(b, on='Issue', how='left')
```

and then droping the unwanted columns of b which got merged in train_data

```
for x in [1,0, 'Issue']:
    del train_data[x]
```

Now the codes look very messy. Does anyone have any simpler codes?

Comment: Can you provide a little snippet of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to avoid the merge operation (and the unwanted columns):

```
train_data['Issue_max'] = train_data.groupby('Issue')['Consumer disputed?'] \
                                    .transform(lambda g: (g.sum() / len(g)) >= 0.2) \
                                    .astype(int)
```

`.astype(int)` at the end is an easy way to convert booleans to `1` or `0`.